# AWS Application Load Balancer + EC2 - 443 listener not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a pretty straight forward setup with a Application Load Balancer with a target group of one ec2 instance running a nginx web server. Both certs I am using are hosted in ACM.

I am having consistent timeout issues with no response at all on HTTPS requests on my 443 listener.

Target Group Health Checks to port 80 on my instance are green and no concerns there.

Though I have noticed the following scattered in the VPC flow logs:

`vpc-aaa 5 IPv4 - 2 subnet-aaa - - 1672796500 55774 my-ip us-east-1 6 my-ip - target-ip - 11 OK eni-aaa - ingress 1672796672 443 target-ip use1-az2 REJECT 688 333165531173`

The odd thing is... I tested a listener on port 8443 with an identical setup to my 443, and **it works**

I have tried looking at the Network Interfaces, VPCs, Subnets, Security Groups, Routing Rules, Certificates...with no luck.

Is this a problem with the nginx config, because I have tried everything on the ALB side, and I am not sure where to go from here.

Anyone with any further insight on this or something similar would be helping mega!

Thanks so much!
[image: ALB]

[image]

Comment: What are ALB security groups?

Comment: Load balancer security group has the following inbound rule:
sgr-03179e168178246e7 IPv4 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that someone filed an abuse case against our domain which led to the ec2 team disabling http + https traffic to our instance.

Ensure to check your emails friends!